# Append <class 'str'> to list

Tags: python

I have a dictionary consisting of multiple files:

```
names = {
    'file_1': file_1,
    'file_1': file_2,
    'file_1': file_3,
}
```

I'm trying to, in a loop, add a certain value at the end of each row:

```
total_rows = []
for name in names:
    for row in names[name].values:
         total_rows.append(row[0].append(name))
```

However, I get that output of `total_rows` is a list of `None` values. Without adding `.append(names[name])` it works. I printed it and:

```
print(type(names[name]))
# output: class <'str'>
```

So I think maybe it is None due to this. My goal is to append in each row, the key of its file.

**TO REPRODUCE IT**
Here is some data example of what are composed those files of:

```
COLA, COLB, COLC
1, 2, 1
3, 2, 1
1, 4, 6
```

My goal is to have this

```
COLA, COLB, COLC, ID
1, 2, 1, file1
3, 2, 1, file1
1, 4, 6, file1
 . . .
4, 6, 7, file3
```

Comment: `.append` returns None. Always. Just do the inner append on line before.

Comment: In your line: `total_rows.append(row[0].append(name))` you have the return value of `row[0].append(name)` being the parameter of `total_rows.append(...)`. That is where your `None` comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you have multiple files and you want to wrap the content of each files into an array, adding an ID column that tells from which file the line is coming from.
Here's how I will do :

```
import pandas as pd

### This is to generate example files

template = """COLA,COLB,COLC
1, 2, 1
3, 2, 1
1, 4, 6"""

def generating_files():
    for i in ['file1','file2','file3']:
        with open(i,'w') as f:
            f.write(template)
            
generating_files()

############# Here's the code #############

myfiles = ["file1",
 "file2",
 "file3",
]

def parsefile(filename):
    ## Use pandas to open the file and change to a list of dict
    ## Not sure how you open your files currently
    return pd.read_csv(filename).to_dict(orient="records")

total_rows = []
for filename in myfiles:
    dictfile = parsefile(filename)
    ## Add a new field to the dict
    for lines in dictfile:
        lines["ID"] = filename
    ## Append total_row
    total_rows.extend(dictfile)

total_rows
```

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if the value in your `dict` is an object or not. But if it's an object like a `list`, you can do this to append to your value:

```
names = {
    'file_1': [1,2,3],
    'file_2': [2,3,4],
    'file_3': [3,4,5],
}
for key, value in names.items():
    value.append(key)

print(names)

#{
#    'file_1': [1,2,3, 'file_1'],
#    'file_2': [2,3,4, 'file_2'],
#    'file_3': [3,4,5, 'file_3'],
#}
```

Answer (score 1):

you get a string value by  doing this beacous you are reading the value

```
names[name]
```

you are reading the value itself

i would try to do it like this

```
file_1 = open("temp.txt" , "r")

names = {
    'file_1': file_1.readlines(),
    'file_2': file_1.readlines(),
    'file_3': file_1.readlines(),
}

total_rows = []
for name in names:
    for row in names[name]:
         total_rows.append(row.replace("\n", " " + name + "\n"))
```